# How to grant free access to network printer A while keeping access restrictions for network printer B

Tags: windows, windows-xp, printer, network-printer

I have an Windows XP network with 2 printers, both of them connected to the same PC. I need the first printer to be freely available to all the network, that is: no user name, no password, no credentials required, just hit the print button and that's it. The second printer must be password protected. I have no problem with the second printer since that's the Windows default, but I just can't find a way to access the first printer without Windows poping up a log-in dialog box.

NICE TO HAVE:

The users of the second printer share 2 PCs, one of them is the one that has the 2 printers attached, so it would be nice if they could have direct access to the printer form the second PC (and form that PC only), once again, no credentials asked when printing from that computer, however anyone trying to print from any other PC ought be forced to provide a user name and password.

Answer (score 0):

This depends if it is on a domain network and how the computers are setup.

I would try is to add the "Everyone" group to Printer A's Security Tab.